# Simulating a Click with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I've found numerous solutions to my question on SO however I am not able to achieve the same results from these answers.

I am trying to test whether a particular function runs or not when a button is clicked. My button looks like this.

```
<button id='send-project-manager-email-button' className={styles.sendEmail} onClick={()=>sendEmail()}>
   Resend Email
</button>
```

I am attempting to test this using a mock function:

```
it('renders disabled button', () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = mount(<SendProjectManagerEmail sendEmail={mockFn}/>);
    const button = wrapper.find('#send-project-manager-email-button');
    button.simulate('click')
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

I have tried multiple variations of this as it appears in other SO questions however I always find that `mockFn` was called 0 times.

Comment: Can you try `onClick={sendEmail}`? Not that it should *really* matter but I wonder if for some reason because it's a function that's being internally called it's somehow putting the invocation onto the next tick.

Comment: @James I get an error saying `sendEmail` is not defined.  This is the name of the function in my component so it isn't defined in my test file.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.... I meant can you make that change to your `button` *in* your component i.e. `<button onClick={sendEmail} />`

Comment: @James Ah yes I misunderstood.  I just tried that now and things still do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unit test working example:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
  sendEmail: 'sendEmail'
};

export const SendProjectManagerEmail = ({ sendEmail }) => {
  return (
    <button id="send-project-manager-email-button" className={styles.sendEmail} onClick={() => sendEmail()}>
      Resend Email
    </button>
  );
};
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import { SendProjectManagerEmail } from './';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

describe('SendProjectManagerEmail', () => {
  it('renders disabled button', () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<SendProjectManagerEmail sendEmail={mockFn} />);
    const button = wrapper.find('#send-project-manager-email-button');
    button.simulate('click');
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58808783/index.spec.tsx
  SendProjectManagerEmail
    ✓ renders disabled button (201ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.604s, estimated 10s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58808783

Comment: The only difference I can find between this method and what I am trying is that I am not passing `sendEmail` as props.  I am declaring the function inside the `SendProjectManagerEmail` component.

Comment: @tdammon Please edit your post, add the completed and minimal reproducing code.